# SQL Query to overwrite the existing JSON Object

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, sql-server-2019

I have the below JSON Object. I need to remove the existing Object values add new one's.

```
{
  "Model": [
    {
      "ModelName": "Test Model",    
      "Object": [
         {
           "ID": 1,
           "Name": "ABC",
         },
         {
           "ID": 11,
           "Name": "ABCD",
         },
         {
           "ID": 15,
           "Name": "ABCDE",
         },
   ]  
}]}
```

New JSON object should be updated to below. I need to completely overwrite the Object.

```
     {
      "Model": [
        {
          "ModelName": "Test Model",    
           "Object": [
              {
                 "ID": 156,
                 "Name": "ABCDEF",
              }             
           ]  
        }]}
```

Comment: What's your question? What's stopping you doing what you need?

Answer (score 0):

In the first step, you need to derive the part(`Object[0]`) which you want to change by going along with `OPENJSON()` functions through `CROSS APPLY` join clauses, and then applying `JSON_MODIFY()` function(s) to update to the desired value as

```
SELECT 
       JSON_MODIFY(JsonData, '$.Model[0]', 
                   JSON_MODIFY(Model, '$.Object', 
                               JSON_QUERY('[{ "ID": 156, "Name": "ABCDEF" }]')) )
       AS JsonData                        
  FROM tab
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(JsonData)
             WITH ( Model  nvarchar(max) '$.Model[0]' AS JSON) AS Q0
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (Q0.Model) 
             WITH ( Object nvarchar(max) '$.Object' AS JSON ) Q1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3e689cae8af008ffda5c8f92f2c1a76e)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

I tried the below query and it worked.

```
DECLARE @Objects TABLE (ID INT, NAME NVARCHAR(20))
DECLARE @ObjectsJsonString NVARCHAR(MAX);

INSERT INTO @Objects values (156, 'ABCDEF');
INSERT INTO @Objects values (180, 'ABCDEFGH');

SET @ObjectsJsonString = (SELECT ID,
                                 NAME
                            FROM @Objects
                              FOR JSON AUTO)

UPDATE ModelTable
  SET JSON_MODIFY(JsonData,'$.Model[0].Object',JSON_QUERY(@ObjectsJsonString))
    WHERE ModelID = 1
```